# Why do rows with no results not show in a SQL group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySql I execute the following:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as number, MONTH(date) AS `month`
FROM
    `numbers`
WHERE (date >= '2013-2-01')
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Returned results

```
number  month
154       2
202       3
2         4
9         5
86        6
73        7
91        8
5         9
```

It only prints out if a record was found, I would like it to print out the following:

```
number  month
0         1
154       2
202       3
2         4
9         5
86        6
73        7
91        8
5         9
0        10
0        11
0        12
```

Comment: You need a month table.

Comment: In general, by the time it comes to the grouping part of processing a query, all the system knows is it has columns containing the grouping keys. It doesn't really know where that data came from. In particular, it's got no way of knowing the full "range" of values that "should" be present and inserting groups based on zero input rows so that all values from the range appear in the result set. It would take special casing (which no vendor does, so far as I'm aware) to know that this is month range data and so should have groups from 1-12.

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer, if you have one (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Comment: In SQL, you can, by default, only select data which exist - see other posts about creating a "fake" table with numbers for each month (or retrieve your data from the DB and splice the data server-side)

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to have a table which contains all months and then use LEFT JOIN on that table, like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(date) as number, all_months.month AS `month`
FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS `month` UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) as all_months
LEFT JOIN
    `numbers`
ON all_months.month = MONTH(numbers.date)
AND date >= '2013-2-01'
GROUP BY all_months.month
```

Working [Demo:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e38bc/10/0)

Regarding your current query, lets say your table contains 3 rows, one record for January and two records for March. RDBMS cannot figure out which are the missing months (unless you explicitly tell the server). The result will be from those 3 rows and after doing a GROUP BY the result will contain 2 rows (one for January and March each).

Comment: That'll work but run explain, and justify the complexity. Much better off to be handled in app logic IMO.

Comment: @AD7six agreed, which is why I upvoted the [comment posted by @Strawberry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234898/why-do-rows-with-no-results-not-show-in-a-sql-group-by/21234964#comment31986314_21234898) above.

Comment: How should I tackle the issue in the application layer? Will I have to have a predetermined array of all the months, and a `if !(in_array($arr, 'Month'))`

Comment: @StevieG I dont have adequate knowledge on the application layer but yes at a highlevel you are correct that you'll have an array of 12 months and then cross check with the DB resultset.